# 404 and 400 on Serilog's Elasticsearch sink

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, system.net.webexception

I have an elasticsearch server and an app writing to it through Serilog + Elasticsearch sink. It worked fine, but suddenly I'm getting `The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found`. I'm getting two of these for http://{ip}:{port}/_template/serilog-events-template - and then two of `The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.` for same response URI.

I'm getting it when creating the logger:

```
_perfElasticLogger = new LoggerConfiguration().WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticUrl))
{
    AutoRegisterTemplate = true,
    LevelSwitch = LevelSwitch,
    IndexFormat = elasticIndex.ToLower() + "-perf-{0:yyyy.MM.dd}",
    ModifyConnectionSettings = ModifyConnectionSettings,
    ConnectionTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1)
}).CreateLogger();
```

Server itself works fine - if I go with browser to the {ip}:{port} it works. Also I can go to http://{ip}:{port}/_template/serilog-events-template (I have no idea what that is, though) and I do get a page with `{}` and not 404 or 400...

Any clue on what's the problem , or how I can move forward debugging it?